# How to create a link with a request parameter to a Servlet in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I want to use JSF component to implement a dynamic breadcrumb.
So my idea is to use this piece of code to pass parameter to my Servlet

```
<c:forEach items="#{sub_steps}" var="sub_step" varStatus="loop">        
    <h:link value="#{sub_step.name}" action="#{homeManager.redirect()}" ajax="false"> <!--  action="#{homeManager.redirect()}" --> 
        <f:param name="sub_step_id" value="#{sub_step.sub_step_id}" />
    </h:link>
</c:forEach>
```

At this point, I see GET request coming going to my server but it is never handled by my servlet.

I have a managed bean with request scope like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="homeManager", eager=true)
@RequestScoped
public class homeManager extends HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet
```

my method redirect method in my managed bean:

```
public String redirect(){
        return "shop";
    }
```

and an extract of my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Shop</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.kino.front.homeManager</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Shop</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/shop</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I expected a redirection to my url mapping shop with the parameter I set in  markup so that my servlet can process the data and render my view with updated data.

Why my method is never called ?
Is it the proper way to pass value from JSF to Servlet ?

Comment: Where did you read about the combination of being a servlet and have jsf annotations on the same class is a solution to some problem? Weird combination

Answer (score 0):

Solution is the replace `h:link` with

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/shop?sub_step_id=#{sub_step.sub_step_id}">
#{sub_step.name}
</a>
```

**UPDATE:**

or even better using JSF component (thanx to @Kukeltje's comment)

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/shop?sub_step_id=#{sub_step.sub_step_id}">
#{sub_step.name}
</h:outputLink>
```

Beside other things (`h:link` does not have `action` and `ajax` attributes), your code does not work because `h:link` appends Faces Context path so it ends up referring to, for example,

`/YourApp/Faces/shop` instead of desired `/YourApp/shop`

Check out your page source before and after applying my suggestion and you will see the difference.

Comment: would `h:outputLink` not be a solution too?

Comment: @Kukeltje, yes it is. And it is even better solution.

Comment: It's not better, its different (you can update it via jsf if you like), otherwise there is not a major advantage (ok, maybe you can 'disable' it and you just see a span)

Comment: @Kukeltje, agreed. 'Better' is not appropriate description. 'More flexible' maybe?